# What are some examples of illnesses that require you to get up in the middle of the night?

Tags: medications, waking-up, restless-sleep

Some people with diabetes get up during the night to test their blood sugar levels. If they don't do this, it is possible that they can pass away in their sleep.

There is another [question](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/3744) here saying that some early drugs for AIDS need to be taken even in the middle of the night.

Are there any other examples of illnesses that require people to get up at night and to not do so is life threatening? What is the name of the AIDS medication above?

Comment: Bipolar causes you to not even sleep at night and can in the medical community be regarded as life threatening although I don't really agree.